# How to bind xsodata in sapui5 table?

Tags: odata, sapui5, hana, hana-xs

I am trying to bind xsodata in sapui5, but i don't know how to instantiate xsodata model in it . Also, is it possible to perform create and update operation with the help of xsodata in sap hana database from sapui5.

Comment: I think that normal ODataModelV2 should work, did you try? Did you try to get $metadata from service?

Comment: yes...I already got $metadata from service,but dont know how to bind it in sapui5.......Is it similarly like normal odata binding.

Comment: what do you mean by "bind it"? You just need to instantiate it via manifest or   ODataModel constructor passing the link to this service, and all should work like with ABAP backend.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply instantiate ODataModel like:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("/yourendpoint.xsodata", true);
```